# Issue while getting data from Firestore in iOS

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from Firestore database, Structure for data is,

```
{
"teamImage"  : "ABC",
"teamName"  : "XYZ",
"players" : [
     "playerImage" : ["mnb","sadja"],
      "playerName" : ["aska","asdaj"]
]
}
```

Code through which i'm trying to retrieve is,

```
func readArray()
{

    let dbRef = Firestore.firestore()
    dbRef.collection("Team").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            print(snapshot!.documents)
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let docId = document.documentID
                let teamName = document.get("teamName") as! String
                let teamImage = document.get("teamImage") as! String
                let players = document.get("players") as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                print(players)
                for items in players
                {
                    let playerName = document.get("playersName") as? [Any]
                    print(playerName)
                }
                print(players)
                print(docId, teamName, teamImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Team name, team Image and players are retrieved fine, but when i try to get data from players array it get crash, players looks like this when retrieved,

```
["playerImage": <__NSArrayM 0x6000024eaa90>(
```

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/basket-ball-tracking.appspot.com/o/%3CUIImage:%200x600002bc8bd0%3E%20size%20%7B4288,%202848%7D%20orientation%200%20scale%201.000000.jpg?alt=media&token=d18dfc89-1a21-45c9-b8f0-7f076cd15bc1,
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/basket-ball-tracking.appspot.com/o/%3CUIImage:%200x600002bc7950%3E%20size%20%7B3000,%202002%7D%20orientation%200%20scale%201.000000.jpg?alt=media&token=58faddd8-b343-4ec9-a09b-740678ccc80b
)
, "playerName": <__NSArrayM 0x6000024eaaf0>(
Ali,
Hamza
)
]

Comment: Please edit the question to be very clear about the data types of each field in the document.  A screenshot of the document might help.  It seems that you might actually have arrays where you actually want a map.  The document browser should be clear about what type of data you're working with.

Comment: "it get crash" Please show error message in console then. Which line causes the crash exactly? `let playerName = document.get("playersName") as? [Any]`? Maybe because it's not from `document`, but from `items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Players is a dictionary of type [String: [String]] (value is array of strings)

```
if let players = document.get("players") as? [String: [String]] {
  let names = players["playerImage"] ?? []
  for name in names {
    print(name)
  }

  let images = players["playerImage"] ?? []
  for image in images {
    print(image)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to get perfect one . @udbhateja